# Repeating same java menu twice on one web page

Tags: jquery

If you use a menu similar to that found on jqueryui.com, how would you go about repeating this menu 2, 3, 4, times as necessary on the same page? I know that if I were to simply copy and paste the entire block, the second menu would not be able to access the .js file.

I've been trying to look at using .clone and appendTo, but I'm not sure if this is the right direction.

TIA...

This code is not mine but is a good example of what I'm looking at:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>accordion demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget.
    Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in,
    condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros.
    Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio.</p>
</div>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus.
    Vivamus hendrerit, dolor aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis velit,
    faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.</p>
</div>
<h3>Section 3</h3>
<div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus.
    Quisque lobortis.Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>List item one</li>
        <li>List item two</li>
        <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: You can try calling accordion function on a class element or can try to live binding on class, by applying a common class to the divs, that you want to apply accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the accordion initialization.

When you call

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
```

Simply add the other ids. For example

```
$( "#accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3" ).accordion();
```

Alternatively, you could simply add a class to all elements you want to apply an accordion and they will all be initialized.

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion();
```

Comment: Thanks, have just adjust for local code and this works a dream!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="accordion1">
    ...
</div>

<div id="accordion2">
    ...
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#accordion1").accordion();
    $("#accordion2").accordion();
});
</script>
```

Comment: As above, thanks for showing me how to implement the code properly!